# How to capture float values from user input to get sum of float values

Tags: python, list, floating-point, sum

The assignment is:

1. Write the code that searches the list for the name of the add-in ordered by the customer.
2. Write the code that prints the name and price of the add-in or the error message, and then write the code that prints the cost of the total order.
3. Execute the program using the following data and verify that the output is correct:

   ```
   Cream
   Caramel
   Whiskey
   chocolate
   Chocolate
   Cinnamon
   Vanilla
   ```

I have executed the main portion of the assignment but don't understand how to capture the values previously inputted to sum/add them.

My code:

```
# Declare variables.
NUM_ITEMS = 5 # Named constant

# Initialized list of add-ins
addIns = ["Cream", "Cinnamon", "Chocolate", "Amaretto", "Whiskey"]

# Initialized list of add-in prices
addInPrices = [.89, .25, .59, 1.50, 1.75]
 # Flag variable
orderTotal = 2.00  # All orders start with a 2.00 charge

# Get user input
# 
addIn = ""

addIn = input("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ")
# Write the rest of the program here.
while addIn != "XXX":
    foundIt = False

    for i in range(0, len(addInPrices)):
        price = addInPrices[i]
        product = addIns[i]
        if addIn == product: 
            foundIt = True
            break

    if foundIt == True:

        print("{} Price is ${}".format(product,price))

    else: 
        print("Sorry, we do not carry that.")

    addIn = input("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ")

# MY COMMENT --- Want to create new list from input above when foundIT == True and sum total to print out total order cost.
    newList=[]  #Create new list to grab values when foundIt == True
    while foundIt == True:

        addCost=price
        newList.extend(addCost)

        foundIt == True
        break

    else:
        foundIt == False

    print(newList)


print("Order Total is ${}".format(orderTotal))
```

I discovered I keep trying to iterate floats(e.g. `addCost`, `price`, etc) or iterate the 'bool' which is not allowed.  Should I have captured the user's input in a list earlier in the code so I could sum for the last step of the exercise?

Should I think of something else besides creating a list to solve the exercise?  If so, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `extend` on your list, you actually want to `append` the item. `extend` concatenates another list onto your list, `append` adds a value to the list.

But in reality, we don't need this list at all for what you want to do. Instead, we can just add the price to the total as we are considering the items. We can print the price here too, and just rely on the `foundIt` flag to output the error message

```
# Declare variables.
NUM_ITEMS = 5 # Named constant

# Initialized list of add-ins
addIns = ["Cream", "Cinnamon", "Chocolate", "Amaretto", "Whiskey"]

# Initialized list of add-in prices
addInPrices = [.89, .25, .59, 1.50, 1.75]
# Flag variable
orderTotal = 2.00  # All orders start with a 2.00 charge
# Get user input
# 
addIn = ""
addIn = input("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ")
# Write the rest of the program here.
while addIn != "XXX":

    foundIt = False

    for i in range(len(addIns)):
        if addIn == addIns[i]:
            print("Found match!")
            orderTotal += addInPrices[i]
            foundIt = True
            print("{} Price is ${}".format(addIns[i],addInPrices[i]))
            addIn = input("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ")
            continue

    print("Sorry, we do not carry that.")
    addIn = input("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ")

print("Order Total is ${}".format(orderTotal))
```

Comment: not sure if this is the correct forum to ask clarification question but in my code I was "mentored" to have a test thus the two foundIt==True lines.  Is it necessary to check each time I write code to ensure it passes the first time?  Also not sure how ```orderTotal += addInPrices[i]``` a traceback does not occur on your line but it did for me addCost=price Error: float not iterable.  Could it be that I did not enclose price in []?  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I think your error was actually on the line below `newList.extend(addCost)` . `addCost = price` should always work no matter what price or addcost is since its just assignment

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addcost of being variable it should be list. extend operator works only with list.

```
# Declare variables.
NUM_ITEMS = 5 # Named constant

# Initialized list of add-ins
addIns = ["Cream", "Cinnamon", "Chocolate", "Amaretto", "Whiskey"]

# Initialized list of add-in prices
addInPrices = [.89, .25, .59, 1.50, 1.75]
 # Flag variable
orderTotal = 2.00  # All orders start with a 2.00 charge

# Get user input
# 
addIn = ""

addIn = input("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ")
# Write the rest of the program here.
while addIn != "XXX":
    foundIt = False

    for i in range(0, len(addInPrices)):
        price = addInPrices[i]
        product = addIns[i]
        if addIn == product: 
            foundIt = True
            break

    if foundIt == True:

        print("{} Price is ${}".format(product,price))

    else: 
        print("Sorry, we do not carry that.")

    addIn = input("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ")

# MY COMMENT --- Want to create new list from input above when foundIT == True and sum total to print out total order cost.
    newList=[]  #Create new list to grab values when foundIt == True
    while foundIt == True:

        addCost=[price]
        newList.extend(addCost)

        foundIt == True
        break

    else:
        foundIt == False

    print(newList)


print("Order Total is ${}".format(orderTotal+sum(addCost)))
```